# Is there a jQuery plugin for outerHTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to overwrite the outerHTML of a few links with the same class name. I just wanted to know if this is not working because jQuery doesn't support `.outerHTML`. If it does, may you reference it? Also, is there a way to make this work:

```
$('.t').each(function() {
    $('.t').outerHTML = '<a href="http://www.google.com">' + 
        '<img src="' + $('.t').attr('src') + '" class="' + $('.t').attr('class') + '" /></a>';
});
```

Comment: What is `.t` in this case? Do you mean `.wrap`? http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Comment: I think this post may be what you're after: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html.

Comment: @William: that post refers to getting outer HTML only.  This question is looking for a method to set the outer HTML.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use outerHTML in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483429/how-to-use-outerhtml-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're just trying to wrap an `<a>` element around each `.t`.  jQuery already has a method for doing this called `.wrap`

You can read the documentation at https://api.jquery.com/wrap/

An example of usage with your question would be:

```
$('.t').wrap('<a href="http://google.com">');
```

---

If you think you really need to set an element's outerHTML, you might want to try using the snippet I wrote yesterday as an [answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html/7337485#7337485).  It mimics the behaviour of `.html()` but allows you to get or set the `outerHTML()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery offers what you want, just not as a complete 'outerHTML' function:

```
$('.t').each( function() {
    // Modify the html directly
    $(this).html('<img src="' + $('.t').attr('src') + '" class="' + $('.t').attr('class') + '" /></a>');
    // Use attr to change href
    $(this).attr('href','http://www.google.com');
});
```

You could also .append() a new $('<img/>') which you have manipulated with .attr() and .addClass() instead of writing out the html string.

Answer (score 0):

Creating simple outerHTML jQuery plugin:

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.outerHTML = function() {
    return $(this).clone().wrap('<div></div>').parent().html();
  }
})(jQuery);


// usage
$("<p>Hello</p>").outerHTML(); //  "<p>Hello</p>"
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use `this` in your each!

```
this.outerHTML
```

To be cross-browser use this jQuery Plugin:

https://github.com/darlesson/jquery-outerhtml

Comment: Which is not supported in Firefox: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html#t05

Answer (score -1):

A new jQuery outerHTML plugin version was release at https://github.com/darlesson/jquery-outerhtml and it seems to do what you want:

```
    $(".t").each(function(){

        var $this = $(this),
            // Get the attribute values
            src = $this.attr("src"),
            className = $this.attr("class");

        $this.outerHTML("<a href='http://www.google.com'><img src='" + src + "' class='" + className + "' /></a>");

    });
```