# Converting long HTML element to string

Tags: javascript, html

How can I convert this whole HTML element:

```
<div class="g">
    <!--m-->
    <div class="rc" data-hveid="95" data-ved="0ahUKEwjWiK-O9-vQAhUH7hoKHcAmBPwQFQhfKAEwCg">
        <h3 class="r">
            <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Something_(Beatles_song)" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','11','AFQjCNGXYioeoJweF-wB1uZUU1NGNI_A3Q','','0ahUKEwjWiK-O9-vQAhUH7hoKHcAmBPwQFghgMAo','','',event)" target="_blank">
                Something (Beatles song) - Wikipedia
            </a>
        </h3>
        <div class="s">
            <div>
                <div class="f kv _SWb" style="white-space:nowrap">
                    <cite class="_Rm">
                        https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/<b>Something</b>_(Beatles_song)
                    </cite>
                    <div class="action-menu ab_ctl">
                        <a class="_Fmb ab_button" href="#" id="am-b10" aria-label="Result details" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" jsaction="m.tdd;keydown:m.hbke;keypress:m.mskpe" data-ved="0ahUKEwjWiK-O9-vQAhUH7hoKHcAmBPwQ7B0IYTAK">
                            <span class="mn-dwn-arw"></span>
                        </a>
                        <div class="action-menu-panel ab_dropdown" role="menu" tabindex="-1" jsaction="keydown:m.hdke;mouseover:m.hdhne;mouseout:m.hdhue" data-ved="0ahUKEwjWiK-O9-vQAhUH7hoKHcAmBPwQqR8IYjAK">
                            <ol>
                                <li class="action-menu-item ab_dropdownitem" role="menuitem">
                                    <a class="fl" href="https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:CRMWFEe8upUJ:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Something_(Beatles_song)+&amp;cd=11&amp;hl=en&amp;ct=clnk&amp;gl=us" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','11','AFQjCNEbZZpTsVP_Rxv695zfNmReizCs7Q','','0ahUKEwjWiK-O9-vQAhUH7hoKHcAmBPwQIAhjMAo','','',event)" target="_blank">
                                        Cached
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="action-menu-item ab_dropdownitem" role="menuitem">
                                    <a class="fl" href="/search?newwindow=1&amp;q=related:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Something_(Beatles_song)+something&amp;tbo=1&amp;sa=X&amp;ved=0ahUKEwjWiK-O9-vQAhUH7hoKHcAmBPwQHwhkMAo">
                                        Similar
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ol>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <span class="st">
                    "<em>Something</em>" is a song by the Beatles, written by George Harrison and released on the band's 1969 album Abbey Road. It was also issued on a double A-sided&nbsp;...
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--n-->
</div>
```

to a Javascript string?

Comment: Where do you want to do that? In jquery?

Comment: @AkhterAlaminFarhan oh, sorry. Javascript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a HTMLElement to a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474605/how-to-convert-a-htmlelement-to-a-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `querySelector` or similar to get the element, and then `outerHTML` to get its HTML (including the element's own tags):

```
alert(document.querySelector(".g").outerHTML);
```

That assumes that the element you want is the *first* element in the document with the class `g`. You'll have to adjust the selector as appropriate, you can use any valid CSS selector. Note that `querySelector` is also available on individual elements (rather than the document as a whole) if you need to search only part of a document, and there's a form that returns a list of *all* matches (`querySelectorAll`) if you need to loop.

Example:

```js
alert(document.querySelector(".g").outerHTML);
```

```html
<div class="g"><!--m--><div class="rc" data-hveid="95" data-ved="0ahUKEwjWiK-O9-vQAhUH7hoKHcAmBPwQFQhfKAEwCg"><h3 class="r"><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Something_(Beatles_song)" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','11','AFQjCNGXYioeoJweF-wB1uZUU1NGNI_A3Q','','0ahUKEwjWiK-O9-vQAhUH7hoKHcAmBPwQFghgMAo','','',event)" target="_blank">Something (Beatles song) - Wikipedia</a></h3><div class="s"><div><div class="f kv _SWb" style="white-space:nowrap"><cite class="_Rm">https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/<b>Something</b>_(Beatles_song)</cite><div class="action-menu ab_ctl"><a class="_Fmb ab_button" href="#" id="am-b10" aria-label="Result details" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" jsaction="m.tdd;keydown:m.hbke;keypress:m.mskpe" data-ved="0ahUKEwjWiK-O9-vQAhUH7hoKHcAmBPwQ7B0IYTAK"><span class="mn-dwn-arw"></span></a><div class="action-menu-panel ab_dropdown" role="menu" tabindex="-1" jsaction="keydown:m.hdke;mouseover:m.hdhne;mouseout:m.hdhue" data-ved="0ahUKEwjWiK-O9-vQAhUH7hoKHcAmBPwQqR8IYjAK"><ol><li class="action-menu-item ab_dropdownitem" role="menuitem"><a class="fl" href="https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:CRMWFEe8upUJ:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Something_(Beatles_song)+&amp;cd=11&amp;hl=en&amp;ct=clnk&amp;gl=us" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','11','AFQjCNEbZZpTsVP_Rxv695zfNmReizCs7Q','','0ahUKEwjWiK-O9-vQAhUH7hoKHcAmBPwQIAhjMAo','','',event)" target="_blank">Cached</a></li><li class="action-menu-item ab_dropdownitem" role="menuitem"><a class="fl" href="/search?newwindow=1&amp;q=related:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Something_(Beatles_song)+something&amp;tbo=1&amp;sa=X&amp;ved=0ahUKEwjWiK-O9-vQAhUH7hoKHcAmBPwQHwhkMAo">Similar</a></li></ol></div></div></div><span class="st">"<em>Something</em>" is a song by the Beatles, written by George Harrison and released on the band's 1969 album Abbey Road. It was also issued on a double A-sided&nbsp;...</span></div></div></div><!--n--></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be a way

> var str=document.getElementsByClassName('g')[0].innerHTML;

Comment: That will only get the parts *inside* the element, not the element's own tags (`<div class="g">` and `</div>`).

Comment: Sorry, it would be outerHtml.