# Store newly appended elements server-side via socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

```js
    // Client
function elemToString(elem){
    return elem.outerHTML
}

let child = document.createElement("div")
child.textContent = "foo"
child.className = "messages"
parent.appendChild(child)
socket.emit('chatMsg', elemToString(child))

//Server
const messages = []

socket.on('chatMsg', elem => {
  messages.push(elem)
})
```

I have a button that creates a div with content, how can i display newly appended divs to everyone and not just the individual client.

Answer (score 0):

The `child` variable is an object. When the same is written on network, it will become something like `[object object]`.

All you need to do is to convert the `DOMElement` as string & send it via socket.
Similarly, when the same is received, it is received as `string`. You will need to convert the string back in to `DOMElement` in order to append it into the `document.`

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474605/how-to-convert-a-htmlelement-to-a-string) to know how to convert a `DOMElement` to string.

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494143/creating-a-new-dom-element-from-an-html-string-using-built-in-dom-methods-or-pro) to know how to convert a string to `DOMElement`.

Basically, your code will need to changed like this:

```
// Client
    let child = document.createElement("div")
    child.textContent = `foo`
    child.className = "messages"
    parent.appendChild(child)

    socket.emit('newDiv', domElementToString(child))

function domElementToString(element) {...}

// Server
    socket.on('newDiv' elem => {
      // show newly appended divs
    })
```

**Update:**

```
// if "messages" are array of DOM elements, then the following will work

function stringToDOMElement(string) {...refer the 2nd reference link...}

socket.on('chatMsg', (elem) => {
  messages.push(stringToDOMElement(elem))
})
```

Comment: I've updated my code, but why are new divs still not visible to others?

Comment: @AlexaJenasoba, sorry for the delay, man! I did not checked stackoverflow for few days.