# Loop through all attributes of an xml node

Tags: javascript, xml

Is there a way with JavaScript to loop through all attributes of a given xml node?

I am hoping that there's a simple method that doesn't involve calling a library (jQuery or other).

Comment: See related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/828311/how-to-iterate-through-all-attributes-in-an-html-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `attributes` collection.

```
for (var i=0; i<node.attributes.length; i++)
{
    var attrib = node.attributes[i];
}
```