# Iterate over attributes in DOM

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get all Attributes from a HTML element with Javascript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048720/get-all-attributes-from-a-html-element-with-javascript-jquery)

I need to retrieve all attributes of a DOM element. I've seen the `getAttribute()` method, but I don't know the names of the attributes in advance. If I use `getElementById()` to retrieve an element, how do I then access all attributes of that element and their values?

Comment: Yeah, I found what I needed at [Get all Attributes from a HTML element with Javascript/jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/828311/how-to-iterate-through-all-attributes-in-an-html-element?rq=1). Sorry.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Each DOM node has an `attributes` property, which is a NamedNodeMap (essentially an array with a few extra features). In particular this means you can get `elem.attributes.length` and loop through them.

Each individual attribute is an Attr object, which has (among other things) `name` and `value` properties.

Note that IE7 and below have a list of all attributes that could possibly be defined (84 in all) whether or not they are actually on the element. You may want to run a quick check for falsy values before actually including an attribute value.

Comment: An attribute can still have a falsy value and do something (e.g., you could have `<div contenteditable></div>`)

Comment: That would have a value of `contenteditable`, just like other boolean attributes ;)

Comment: perhaps a good use of `for..of` ?