# How to add one tags attribute in another tag using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to know that, is it possible to bypass one tags data-attribute into another tag using javascript or jquery ?

For example, if I write this tag `<span id="mycode" data-attribute="my-code"></span>` in anywhere inside body, the data-attribute tag will be append automatically in body tag `<body data-attribute="my-code"></body>`

When I create a template, the `<body>` tag is without any attribute. I want that, when I'll write this tag with attribute (`<span data-attribute="my-code">`), only the attribute will be add in body tag `(<body>)`.

**If somebody know, please help me.**

Comment: What did the OP try? How would the OP start solving the just described scenario?

Comment: @PeterSeliger OP means...?

Comment: Look, <span id="mycode" data-attribute="code-one" data-message="Well Done Dear" data-number="5" data-status="Active">

If i write this code in my template, then these data-xxxx attributes will add inside <body> tag..

I hope you understand..

Comment: _**OP**_ stands for _**o**riginal **p**ost_ or _**o**riginal **p**oster_, hence you in the context of this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP should have a look into ...

- [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign),
- an `HTMLElement`'s [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) property
- and into e.g. [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) from the selector API.

The `Object.assign` based approach used by the beneath provided example code merges the `dataset` object of the second provided source-element ... `document.querySelector('#mycode')` ... into the `dataset` object of the first provided target-element ... `document.body`. Which means that every property of the former gets assigned as property to the latter thus also overwriting equally named already existing properties.

**Notes**

- `?.` is the [Optional Chaining Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), which allows chained property access in a fail safe way (in case properties do not exist).
- `??` is the [Nullish Coalescing Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing) which here gets used for falling back to a default value in case the left hand side value is either `null` or `undefined`.

```js
console.log('before ...', { body: document.body });

Object
  .assign(
    document.body.dataset,
    document.querySelector('#mycode')?.dataset ?? {}
  );

console.log('after ...', { body: document.body });
```

```css
#mycode code { background-color: #ddd; font-weight: bolder; }
```

```html
<span
  id="mycode"
  data-attribute="code-one"
  data-message="Well Done Dear"
  data-number="5"
  data-status="Active"
>
  span with a lot of
  <a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*">
    <code>data-*</code>
    global attributes
  </a>
</span>
```

Comment: Will this data-xxxx apply if i write <span id="mycode">.... Otherwise this code Won't apply...  Am I right ?

Comment: @AsmaBintaYounus ... the code is straightforward it assigns any `data-*` related value of a source element's (here: `document.querySelector('#mycode')`) `dataset` to the target element (here: `document.body`). Thus, immediately after the assignment the `body` element will feature all these `data-*` related attributes as well. Didn't the OP run/execute the above provided example code? The before/after logging proves what was just said.

Comment: Awesome brother, Just awesome... You actually did what I was thinking and looking for. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You can access `data-XXX` attributes using the `dataset` property. Then simply assign from one element to another.

```
document.body.dataset.attribute = document.getElementById("mycode").dataset.attribute;
```

Comment: how can I do it...?

Comment: You just put that in your JavaScript code. If you're adding the `mycode` span dynamically, just add that after the code that adds it.

Comment: Look, <span id="mycode" data-attribute="code-one" data-message="Well Done Dear" data-number="5" data-status="Active">

If i write this code in my template, then these data-xxxx attributes will add inside <body> tag..

I hope you understand..

Comment: It won't happen automatically, you need to write code like I showed to do it.

Comment: If you need to copy all the `data-XXX` attributes, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046481/looping-through-elements-data-attributes for how to loop through them.

Comment: @Barmar ... The iteration is not needed since the OP wants to assign all properties of the source-element's `dataset` to the target-element's `dataset`. And since the latter are objects `Object.assign` already does the trick.