# javascript object iterate through element for attribute

Tags: jquery

Below, I am trying to iterate through each attribute in an input element.  It isn't working and I'm not sure why.  Is this an incorrect use of the object named input?  How do I change this?

```
<script>
   $('form.trade').submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      input=$(this).find(':input:first');
      value='';

      $.each(input.attributes, function(i, attrib){
        if (attrib.name!='type'){
            value +=attrib.name + ":" + attrib.value + ";";
        }
      });
      });
</script>
<form class="trade" id="24243">
<input type="hidden" available="4" pid="24243" cardname="something" yay="blah">
Available: <p class="available">4</p>
<input type="submit" value="add card">
</form>
<br/>
<form class="trade" id="24245">
<input type="hidden" available="7" pid="24243" cardname="somethik" yay="blakk">
Available: <p class="available">7</p>
<input type="submit" value="add card">
</form>
```

Comment: doesn't the developer console state an error or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's "attributes" on the input array that doesn't make sense.

```
$.each(input.attributes
```

The result of `$(this).find(':input')` returns a jQuery selection (array) of items.

Are you trying to iterate through the inputs attributes? `$.each(input[i].attributes` is what you're looking to do, where `i` is an iterator through the `input` collection.

~ Here's what you want to do:

```
<script>
      $('form.trade').submit(function(e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           var $inputs=$(this).find(':input:first');
           var value='';
           $inputs.each(function(i,input){
             $.each(input.attributes, function(j,attrib){
                 if (attrib.name!=='type'){
                value +=attrib.name + ":" + attrib.value + ";";
                 }   
             });
           });
           console.log(value); // what do you want to do with value??
      });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess I have to go through the input first.  I'm not sure why, but it solved it easily enough.

```
        value='';
        input.each(function(){
        $.each(this.attributes, function(i, attrib){
            if (attrib.name!='type'){
                value +=attrib.name + ":" + attrib.value + ";";
            }
        });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have used plain javasript:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('testElement');
for (var i = 0; i < elem.attributes.length; i++) {
    var att = elem.attributes[i];
    if (att.specified == true) {
    console.log(att.name + " " + att.value);
    }
}
```

[How to iterate through all attributes in an HTML element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/828311/how-to-iterate-through-all-attributes-in-an-html-element)